# How to move content within fields in a page layout?

Tags: powershell, content-type, page-layout, content, data

I'm working on a requirement where I'm adding a few fields in an already existing Page Layout and also renaming all the fields. After adding the fields via code,I want to move content within fields via PowerShell so that the look of the page remains the same like before.Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a copy of the script in [PowerShell Update Publishing Page Properties](http://sharepointcore.blogspot.dk/2012/04/powershell-update-publishing-page.html) it should be easy to modify it into moving content between fields as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!Appreciate it.
That link helped me a lot! :)